BitLocker asks for recovery key that I don't have - Can I work around that, maybe by restoring secureboot variables?
My wife has this Asus laptop. It's got some issues that may or may not be hardware (trackpad stops working, and for a while, going to UEFI would make it work again, but it's been a week or 2 that workaround doesn't have any effect anymore).
I've previously booted the laptop on Linux to check whether the trackpad was working, which I tried doing again this time (thinking, since not working in UEFI, that might be a physical issue, maybe some wiring issue...).
I booted some linux (Ubuntu, I believe it was a server version) and got a message about the shim that quickly disappeared, replaced by BitLocker recovery screen.
Ever since I haven't been able to boot the original Windows. I wasn't aware the drive was encrypted. It is not tied to an MS account, anyway I checked the only MS account that was ever used on it and it doesn't have a BitLocker recovery key.
BitLocker screen states:

"Enter the recovery key for this drive. You need to enter your recovery key because Secure Boot policy has unexpectedly changed."

I had a look at the secureboot configuration on the laptop, and I can see several Canonical entries.
In general, I want the data back. Either through booting that Windows install again, or accessing the data another way (I don't have any problem reinstalling the laptop).
At the moment, my theory is the Canonical entries are new and caused a change which means the TPM won't unseal the key anymore.
Any way I could remove those Canonical keys, in the hope to restore the previous state?
I can also use a "Reset to setup mode", but I'm afraid it'll void any chance or recovery. The UEFI allows me to "export", "update" and "delete":

Platform Keys
Key ExchangeKeys
Authorized Signatures
Forbidden Signatures
Authorized TimeStamps

Updating offers to load default ones, or load from external media.
I'm thinking maybe if I reset some of these, I'll get back to a state where the TPM will accept unsealing (for now, I've exported all of them).

Without the Recovery Key data recovery is impossible. Once the Recovery Key is required there is no way to bypass that prompt.

"Enter the recovery key for this drive. You need to enter your recovery key because Secure Boot policy has unexpectedly changed." In order to use Linux, did you disable Secure Boot? Then turn it on. Other than that, if you have no disk image from before, there's little that can be done.

This question is similar to: Bitlocker recovery key. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Ramhound Do you have any (ideally MS) source to back that up?

@DrMoishePippik Thanks, I changed to clarify (I want the data). No I didn't disable secure boot to boot Linux.

@user1532080 - Yes; There is Microsoft documentation that states as much, it’s extremely generic, so likely unsatisfactory so I won’t link to it. The only way data recovery would be poi’s is if you could suspend BitLocker protection, which of course isn’t possible in its current state, since you need to provide the recovery key. Installing Ubuntu made system configuration changes that kicked off the protection mechanism that now requires the recovery key. Clearing the TPM won’t directly result in the loss of the stored key, I suspect, that already happen.

@Ramhound I'd be happy to read that link if you could provide it! Without it, my theory is the TPM doesn't not arrive into a state where it would unseal the key, because the measures have changed. I haven't installed Linux, just tried booting a live CD. Assuming that is what caused a change, the platform boot measures are now incorrect so no unsealing. But if I could get the plaform measures back, unsealing could happen again. What I'm getting from your comment would be that BitLocker would have some kind of "fuse" that would be blown as soon as measurements wouldn't match.

@user1532080—Asking for the Recovery Key is a security measure that only occurs when configuration changes are detected.

If the account on the system was Microsoft account (and not a local-only), one may be able to get the recovery key from that online account. I have no idea how but it may be accessible from account.microsoft.com, "Devices" menu item.

I don't know that the suggest dupe is best, though it is adequate. There are a variety of questions on this site regarding Bitlocker recovery keys though. Here's a search to get you started: https://superuser.com/search?q=bitlocker+recovery

Thanks everyone, I ended up reinstalling the laptop.
